# POST response with file and JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, http, post, http-post

I've got POST method which responds with a file. And right after file download I also want to show the message on the UI, that was generated during the file creation in the code (were there any errors, are all items included in the file etc.).

My question is how to implement such behaviour in most appropriate way?

now I've got 2 ideas:

1. sending another POST method right after download, which will return
   JSON with message contents. Which seems to be quite complicated
   since I should be storing on the server objects with messages for
   each created file
2. sending a cookie with the same response, that will contain message
   contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both of your solutions should work in theory.  I am assuming here that cookie headers sent back with an octet stream response will be honoured and instantly accessable via javascript.  I've not tried this out myself.

I have two more ideas which might give you some inspiration:

**Simple**

In the POST handler before you output the file to the user, you could set a session variable containing the message you want to display.  Then after the file is downloaded, make a 2nd request to GET that message from the session.   Since it would get overwritten each time, it might get a bit unreliable if the user made lots of POSTs at once.

**More complicated**

For a totally asynchronous solution, in the past I have used services in this way:

```
POST /process_this -> "{'status':'ok', 'id':123}"
GET /status?id=123 -> "{'status':'processing', 'progress':'45%'}"
GET /status?id=123 -> "{'status':'processing', 'progress':'85%'}"
GET /status?id=123 -> "{'status':'ready', 'meta':{'data':'message'}}"
GET /download?id=123 -> Binary file stream
```

It gives you the ability to always respond instantly and do some cool progress bar on the frontend.  Also you could have a queue system if the processing is intensive.  But on the downside, you need to write the processor as a seperate module and have it talking to a database or something that saves state.

**Other**

Some other thoughts I had included:

- Storing the meta data within the file itself.  (What is the response file format?)
- Using multipart responses (not sure how compatible browsers are on this yet)
- Using a combination of your two ideas if cookies are not big enough to hold all of the message.